# A combinatoric question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Given three types of balls, red, green and blue. The number of each type of balls is denoted as *R*,*G*, and *B*. The total number of balls *N* is even. We (uniformly) randomly group balls into pairs (so we have *N/2* pairs). What is the expected number of red-green pairs?

I tried to run simulations on this, but ideally I want to find a closed form formula. Any ideas?

Comment: This question was downvoted without comment. Please provide constructive feedback when possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line the pairs up and label them.  Let $X_k$ be the indicator random variable that the $k$-th pair is red-green (that is, $X_k$ equals one if it is or zero if it is not).  The expected value of this random variable is therefore the probability that the $k$-th pair is red-green.  All such random variables have *identical distribution* (although not independent), therefore their expectations are equal.$$\forall k\in\{1..N/2\}~.~\mathsf E(X_k)=\mathsf E(X_1)$$

Let $X$ be the count for red-green pairs.  This will equal $\sum_{k=1}^{N/2} X_k$ and **expectation is linear**, so the expectation for this count is:$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X)&=\mathsf E(\sum_{k=1}^{N/2}X_k)\\[0.5ex]&\vdots\end{align}$$